# short unique identifier string in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an unique invoice id in PHP and currently doing this as following:

```
md5(time().$userId);
```

I may have concurrent users, so I'm adding user id as well to make sure it is unique, but the md5 hashing is 32 character long, is there any way to limit the output short (eg, 8-10 characters, if possible) while ensuring uniqueness?

NB: The output characters has to be same, therefore, just concating user id with time is not actually what I'm looking for since user id could be variable length, eg: 5, 20 or 100.

Comment: You can use this as well: [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: The value has to be unique ***in what space***? Using a decentralised algorithm to generate a unique value is all about collisions and the likeliness of collisions occurring. The variables that play in to this are the length of the value, the frequency with which you generate new values, the size of the alphabet (characters you want to use in the value) and the quality of the algorithm used. You'll have to specify all these if you want a *proper* answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to ensure uniqunes

`time()` works fine for your purpose, since you're concatenating it with `$userId`.

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.substr.php) to take only parts of a string.

---

With that said, there are other ways to get unique strings in php

The one I find myself using more often than not is [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php). Notice the `pseudo`, it's not entirely random.

You can use it like this `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(2))`, where `2` is the length of *bytes*, so it will equal to 4 characters.

---

You can also use [`urandom`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom) if you're on linux via [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) OR even better, use [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.fread.php)

While it's better than the pseudo approach it's limited to the OS.

---

[`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) Also works fine.

---

If you really want something truly random, I suggest https://www.random.org/.

> The randomness comes from atmospheric noise

They have an API you can use.

---

[`random_bytes`](http://php.net/random_bytes) (as suggested by @deceze) also works fine, do note that it's only available in PHP > 7

Pick your poison.

Comment: You can simply `fread` from `urandom`, no need for `exec`. I'd also point at [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/random_bytes).

Comment: I'd be careful about recommending `uniqid`; despite its name nothing guarantees its uniqueness, especially if you have more than one server/processor generating ids.

Comment: Agreed, but for OP's purpose, I don't think it's a bad suggestion. I doubt the collision will be a problem, and if he concatenates with `$userId` it should work fine.

Comment: Same for `time`; even if prefixed it only works if you're generating no more than one id per second per prefix.

Comment: Now that may be a legit problem. If he generates more than 1 id persecond, perhaps [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) would be better.

Answer (score -1):

If i want to do this, use $userId.time()
I think this is unique because an user can't submit more than one order in a moment

Comment: They can’t, no? Also, this is about *invoice* ids, and maybe the system needs to generate several invoices in a batch.